# Accordion using summary and details tags - how to open slowly

Tags: javascript

I've built an accordion using details and summary tags. I added some javascript for closing one item when another opens. The content fades in. This looks quite good. Now I would like to add some animation so that the items open more slowly. There's plenty of information on that when using DIVs. However, I prefer the built-in HTML tags, since authors can edit this type of accordion more easily and won't mess up everything.

HTML

```
<details>
<summary>Test<em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</em></summary>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing </p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Test<em> Lorem ipsum dolor</em></summary>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing</p>
</details>
```

CSS

```
summary {
    background: #DEEBF6;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444444;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

summary:hover {
    background: #cfe1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
details p {
    padding: 15px;
}
details[open] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
details[open] summary {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
   display: none;
}
summary::before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    content: '\27A5';
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: inline-block;
    background: #4d4d4d;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #cfe1f1;
}
summary:hover::before {
    color: #cfe1f1;
}
details[open] summary::before {
    content: '\27A6';
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
details[open] summary ~ * {
  animation: sweep .8s ease-in-out;
}
summary em {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}
@keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0;}
  100%  {opacity: 1;}
}
```

JS

```
$("details").click(function(event) {
  $("details").not(this).removeAttr("open");
});
```

You can see the working example on Codepen:

[Example of accordion on Codepen](https://codepen.io/paul-klee/pen/wvgMNQz)